# displaying UIPickerView over current ViewController xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

Here is my current problem.  I have a UIViewController setup with its data and everything on a small sized view controller.  What I am trying to see is if it is possible to connect that to a separate view controller.  For example I have a view controller that has a user click a button.  Upon pressing the button the UIPicker ViewController would pop up from the bottom and I could go from there.  I know how to enable this if the picker is on the same view controller.  However, I have no idea how to if its on its own ViewController.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to put the picker view on the same view controller and make it hidden, and, when they press the button, unhide it or load the other view controller when they press the button; this will display the other view controller, not what's on the current one.